# repo: stuck while syncing (also with -f)

Tags: android, git, synchronization, repo

Last day I wanted to do repo sync (I'm compiling android sources), and then I noticed that it got stucked in 99%

I did some researchs and people adviced to use repo sync -f, but the problem was the same. Also in the android official page, they said that you can try this command "sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=0", but also It doesn't work.

Other people that are syncing the same repo as me don't have these problems, so I used this command to know what was happening (repo --trace sync -c -d -f -j8)

Here is the wierd part:

.....

: export GIT_DIR=/home/yaymalaga/AOSPA+/.repo/projects/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.8.git
: git rev-parse --verify refs/tags/android-5.0.2_r1^0 1>| 2>|
: load refs /home/yaymalaga/AOSPA+/.repo/projects/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.8.git
Fetching project platform/prebuilts/clang/darwin-x86/host/3.4
: parsing /home/yaymalaga/AOSPA+/.repo/projects/prebuilts/clang/darwin-x86/host/3.4.git/config

: export GIT_DIR=/home/yaymalaga/AOSPA+/.repo/projects/prebuilts/clang/darwin-x86/host/3.4.git
: git rev-parse --verify refs/tags/android-5.0.2_r1^0 1>| 2>|
: load refs /home/yaymalaga/AOSPA+/.repo/projects/prebuilts/clang/darwin-x86/host/3.4.git

And here it stucks. I also tried removing .repo folder and doing repo sync agin, but when downloading sources it stuck too (99%), and the same using repo sync -f, so any idea what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried nslookup ?

You can edit your /etc/hosts file with the addresses for:

```
74.125.71.82 googlesource.com
173.194.66.82 googlecode.l.googleusercontent.com
216.58.210.161 storage-ugc.l.googleusercontent.com
173.194.67.82 android.googlesource.com
216.58.211.193 storage.googleapis.com
```

I have it this way, but maybe you should check with nslookup.

Check also if your ethernet cable is alright, if you are using one. I had to change mine.

I think it should work with this, but...

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's a good idea and it can help other people too!

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, sometimes is a project not downloading right.

http://shellswissknife.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/long-repo-sync.html

I found this code to download the projects one by one and check with a log.txt if something is missing.

Comment: Thanks, I also found that was becouse a project that didn't get downloaded, but in other machines It downloaded, so I deleted the code and sync again.